# battery drain when phone idle

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, battery, battery-life, lg-g4

I'm using LG G4 H818 with android 6.0 All of the sudden my battery started to get drained when I'm not using it at all, mostly over night.
For example, it goes from 100% to 45% over night when I turned off pretty much everything like wifi, data, location, sync etc.

When I turn on the flight mode, everything looks good and I may lose only 2% of my battery, except I can't get calls and since I should be on call for work, that's not a good option.

I have also installed some battery usage app and top processes related are:

- android/OS
- system/android/log.d

I also changed battery in case my previous battery was broken, this doesn't helped either.

Today, I did a factory reset, wiped cache partition and of course there is no app installed and still the same.

And, one more thing, my phone gets hot while using/charging, but not when I'm using it. Any suggestion about how to fix this issue?

Comment: It used to happen to my micromax canvas 5 too. And to my current lenovo k6 note too. But on my this stopped happening when the service centre re did all the android software on it for a completely different reason. So i think the software is the problem here. See if you can flash your phone and whether the problem disappears Or maybe your phone is old and the battery is mostly gone useless. Try changingthe battery. If it still drains even with new batter then the problem is the android software in the phone.